# How do I limit records for Influx using flux?

Tags: influxdb, influxdb-2, flux-influxdb

I'm new with **Influx**, and although I can get `range`, `filter`, `sort` and `group` to work, I just can't get `limit` to work.

I'm using **Influx OSS 2.3** and I'd assume the query should look like this:

```
from(bucket: "readings") 
    |> range(start: - 1d) 
    |> limit(n:10)
```

I've tried both through the Data explorer and the C# sdk, but it always returns 400 records.

If I use `offset` I'm not getting any records:

```
from(bucket: "readings") 
    |> range(start: - 1d) 
    |> limit(n:10, offset:2)
```

Thanks for the help

Comment: The limit is per table (series). How many tables does the result with 400 records comes in, if you check raw data result in Data explorer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe @alespour was on the right track. If you have tags, these will implicitly group the data into independent tables. In flux, each operation is applied to each table independently, so if you have 40 distinct tag values, a call to `limit(n: 10)` would return 400.

Using `group()` with no arguments will drop grouping and the number of records you specify will be applied to all results.

```
from(bucket: "readings") 
    |> range(start: - 1d) 
    |> group()
    |> limit(n:10)
```